# Add Items to ListView in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

**Scenario:**

User `Login`---> Launch `MainActivity` which has a `Navigation drawer`--> From menu in actionbar he goes to new activity

In the new activity I have a `edittext` with a simple `button`.

Now If I add some text to edittext and click button I am placing the edittext in a bundle to pass it to the MainActivity.

Now my problem is that I'm able to pass the intent and get the bundle, but when I try to add that text to listview app crashes.

Here is my Activity Code:

```
addlist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnaddlist);
  findViewById(R.id.btnaddlist).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtlist);
                    Intent i = new Intent(CreateList.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    String ItemName = edit.getText().toString();
                    // Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
                    bundle.putString("ListItemName", ItemName);
                    // Add the bundle to the intent
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

}
```

This is my HomeFragment:

```
ListView lv;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    lv = (ListView)rootView .findViewById(R.id.list);
    Bundle itemintent = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    String ItemName = itemintent.getString("ListItemName");
    if (ItemName.equals("ListItemName")) {
        /** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(ItemName);
        /** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
        ArrayAdapter<String> Listadapter;
        Listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(Listadapter);
        Listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        return rootView;
}
```

Logcat Error:

```
05-01 22:54:07.116: D/AndroidRuntime(19368): Shutting down VM
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368): Process: com.sample.example, PID: 19368
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.example/com.sample.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at com.sample.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:28)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5968)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
05-01 22:54:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(19368):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy approach; In your `MainActivity` get the `String` from `bundle` and save it to another `String`. Later pass that `String` to your `Fragment`s with `Argument`s or better still `Bundle` itself.

Now to your problem `String ItemName = itemintent.getString("ListItemName");` can be translated as `String ItemName = null` why because `getString("ListItemName")` returned `null` you should have gone with

```
String ItemName = itemintent.getString("ListItemName"
                    ,"this default value helps prevent NPE"); //was added in api 12
```

with this your **Error** will go, but that will not be the ultimate solution,since you want a returned `String`, for that go up to the easy approach. *this is a wild guess,which i am good at* I am thinking the reason for the `Bundle` `Intent` being `nullified` is because maybe your `Activity` was recreated using the same `Intent` through that it got `nullfied`

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, you are getting the data in your Activity, but not in your fragment. Maybe you can't get the intent data that started your activity in your fragment, but I find that strange.

You can make a work-around. When your main activity is created, get that data and save it to a public variable.

```
public String itemName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
           itemName = extras.getString("ListItemName");
        }
        else{
          // Something else is wrong
          finish();
        }
    }
```

And then in you fragment do this

```
 String ItemName = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).itemName;
```

Comment: @Bojan-Sorry, Its a typo. Updated my ques

Comment: do you get the data in your activity?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your error clearly states

java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

So it is at

`if (ItemName.equals("ListItemName"))` in which `ItemName` is null

Can you try

`this.getArguments().getString("ListItemName")`

also pass this using

`fragment.setArguments(bundle);`

The below is wrong

`Bundle itemintent = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
String ItemName = itemintent.getString("ListItemName");`

you are accessing the intent of activity in which bundle values may be null